# extjs 4 menu no longer working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, extjs

My app has been working successfully literally for years, until a very recent build (update) of Chrome in which menu component is no longer working as it is expected to work.

To prove this, you can open an official [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/themes/index.html) and check Menu button inside the top `Basic Panel With Toolbars`. If you move cursor to `Sub-items` and then try to choose `Item 1` or `Item 2`, you will fail - a sub-item blinks and gets hidden.

Comment: it works for me  (on chrome on windows)

Comment: I have `43.0.2357.65 m` build. What build of Chrome do you have?

Comment: See: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301116-Submenus-disappear-in-Chrome-43-beta

Comment: Thanks, Evan! I will try a fix from that forum thread.